# Pass response of one REST API to another API as header in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I've a use case, currently I'm using two micro-services one is for auth and other one is related to other niche. Now when I call login API of auth service it will return secret key and other stuff, it should be automatically added in header of my other service API. How can I do this.

I'm trying to use mapping template.

Comment: REST is stateless so whatever you are trying you wont be able to achieve that on the server side. You can do that on your client side and create the client request handler where it checks if the client is authenticated it adds the auth headers to all the subsequent rest request

Answer (score 1):

This might be an overkill, depending on your use case, but you can create a [custom authorizer lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) for your niche API-G and add following logic:

1. If auth data is present in the request headers, validate it and let request pass
2. If no auth data is present, call auth API, get auth token and attach it to request.

Also, if your authentication API conforms to OIDC standard then you can also  create [IAM OpenId provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html), attach it to Cognito identity pool, and configure API to use Cognito authentication.